# How to enable AB deployment with Amazon S3 Static website

Tags: amazon-s3, akamai

I have a usecase where I deploy static part of the website is hosted in a S3 bucket, fronted with akamai. Based on the context traffic will route to static content in S3 or, backend APIs deployed in EC2. I want to enable AB deployment to the content in S3 bucket. In a new static content deployment. current static is removed from the S3 bucket and new content is copied. This can take up to 10 to 20 seconds downtime. What is the correct AB deployment approach with S3 static website hosting with zero downtime?

I can think of two solutions.

1. Having 2 S3 buckets and change akamai mappings (this is not ideal, since change the akamai mapping require more process and teams involved in a release)
2. Enable akamai caching for static content (maybe 5 minutes),

Is there any better solutions other than above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy first and then to rename actual to old and new to actual

```
aws s3 --recursive mv s3://your_bucket/actual s3://your_bucket/old

aws s3 --recursive mv s3://your_bucket/new s3://your_bucket/actual
```

The switch would be fast.